# mariadb - EXPLAIN works but ANALYZE throws ERROR 1064 (42000) error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mariadb, explain

I want to see the execution plan of a query to find out why it is slow, but ANALYZE does not seem to work, it throws an error on the same query that EXPLAIN accepts.

```
MariaDB [dbx]> explain select `id` from `pics` where `user_id` = '3';
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pics  | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 4       | const | 1087 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [dbx]> analyze select `id` from `pics` where `user_id` = '3';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select `id` from `pics` where `user_id` = '3'' at line 1
```

I use `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.14-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**EXPLAIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) will get the execution plan for a query

[**ANALYZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) recalculates the index statistics. So just run

```
ANALYZE TABLE `pics`;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: OK. I did not carefully read. It seems the `analyze statement` command will come with mariadb 10.1. So it can not work with 10.0.14 . https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/administration-commands/analyze-statement/